# Docker combine curl and php containers

Tags: php, docker, curl, webserver, docker-compose

I've just started to learn how to use Docker. For learning purposes i'm trying to create webserver app (nginx+php+mysql) and now i have some questions.

I want to use php with my own build of curl (with http2 support etc.). I built image but can i use it as separate container and let container with php use curl library from curl's container (using docker compose) or i can only use it as base image for php container?

And second question - if i can use it as separate container, how to let this container to listen for commands (now it stops after starting). I know that i should set ENTRYPOINT but what should it be?

Comment: basically you have to link the containers and the reason your container stops is that the startup `CMD` is finishing after some seconds, you need some `CMD` (or entrypoint) that is keep running without stoping.

Comment: @Edwin as an example - i took [this](https://github.com/nanoninja/docker-nginx-php-mysql) and now i want it's php container to use my curl container (7.57 version) for curl instead of it's own curl (7.38 version). to do this i add 'depends_on: curl' in docker-compose.yml but phpinfo displays curl 7.38. Maybe this is cos curl container stops, but is there any parameter like '-t' in docker run in docker-compose?